# Play framework 1.2.4 Error while loading DocViewerPlugin

Tags: gwt, playframework

I've a web application based on Play 1.2.4 and GWT. 
It works well on my own computer, but it does not work on another one.
It looks like the error comes from Play, but I use the same version of play on both computers...

Could you help me with this error please ?

Thank you very much

```
~        _            _
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/
~
~ play! 1.2.4, http://www.playframework.org
~
~ Ctrl+C to stop
~
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option UseSplitVerifier; sup
port was removed in 8.0
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
13:43:16,622 INFO  ~ Starting C:\AppRessources\AppWeb
13:43:16,638 INFO  ~ Module crud is available (C:\play-1.2.4\modules\crud)
13:43:16,638 INFO  ~ Module secure is available (C:\play-1.2.4\modules\secure)
13:43:19,696 ERROR ~

@6kb811e5p
Error loading plugin LoadingPluginInfo{name='DocViewerPlugin', index=1000, url=f
ile:/C:/play-1.2.4/modules/docviewer/app/play.plugins}

Oops: ClassFormatException
An unexpected error occured caused by exception ClassFormatException: null

play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
        at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler$1.findType(ApplicationCompiler.
java:195)
        at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler$1.findType(ApplicationCompiler.
java:144)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType
(LookupEnvironment.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.r
esolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveTyp
e(BinaryTypeBinding.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFro
mTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1264)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFro
mVariantTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1316)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeArg
umentsFromSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1107)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFro
mTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1269)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.createMeth
od(BinaryTypeBinding.java:486)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.createMeth
ods(BinaryTypeBinding.java:554)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.cacheParts
From(BinaryTypeBinding.java:334)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBina
ryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:719)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBina
ryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:699)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.accept(Compiler.java:294)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType
(LookupEnvironment.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.r
esolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveTyp
e(BinaryTypeBinding.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedTypeBinding.res
olve(ParameterizedTypeBinding.java:835)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveTyp
e(BinaryTypeBinding.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveTyp
eFor(BinaryTypeBinding.java:901)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.getField(B
inaryTypeBinding.java:735)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.findField(Scope.java:8
49)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BlockScope.getBinding(BlockS
cope.java:472)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.QualifiedNameReference.resolveT
ype(QualifiedNameReference.java:984)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.resolveType(Message
Send.java:344)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.resolveType(Message
Send.java:344)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.resolve(LocalD
eclaration.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Block.resolve(Block.java:101)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.IfStatement.resolve(IfStatement
.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Block.resolve(Block.java:101)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.IfStatement.resolve(IfStatement
.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resol
veStatements(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.resolveStatem
ents(MethodDeclaration.java:191)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resol
ve(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:403)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDec
laration.java:1096)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDec
laration.java:1184)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.reso
lve(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:535)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:743)

        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:444)

        at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler.compile(ApplicationCompiler.jav
a:282)
        at play.classloading.ApplicationClasses$ApplicationClass.compile(Applica
tionClasses.java:277)
        at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadApplicationClass(Applica
tionClassloader.java:164)
        at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadClass(ApplicationClasslo
ader.java:84)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at play.plugins.PluginCollection.loadPlugins(PluginCollection.java:158)
        at play.Play.init(Play.java:294)
        at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:158)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.<init>(Cla
ssFileReader.java:369)
        at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler$1.findType(ApplicationCompiler.
java:163)
        ... 47 more
13:43:19,726 WARN  ~ You're running Play! in DEV mode
13:43:20,115 INFO  ~ Listening for HTTP on port 9000 (Waiting a first request to
 start) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 and Play 1.2.x don't mix. Source: the same issue as reported on the [Play Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/SHSMhc-W8zQ/discussion).

Answer (score -1):

I think this should be the version of the problem, if the words are replaced java7 not have this problem, I am also there, and then I replaced java7, then it is normal

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Just install Java 7 and don't forget to set JAVA_HOME and PATH variables to it.